# The Raycast node not working as intended

Tags: geometry-nodes, splines

[image: Nodes]

[image: Unexpected behaviour of spline]

I want to make some random splines that start from an object and end on another (in this case start from plane and end on the surface of Suzanne).

Most of them follow geometry nodes setup but some choose to rotate in direction of world origin and end exactly on world origin. I set a density value for the point distribution node to have only one wrong spline in viewport which is outlined.

Also, there is data in the spreadsheet tab of raycast hit position output in which no value is zero vector and still it's not working. Am I missing something?

[Blend_File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PTkPGxOoPbO42jdOXQbzMes9erLnZvl8/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: would you mind providing blend file? wo we don't have to rebuild everything to test that...

Comment: @Chris yeah sure, [Blend_File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PTkPGxOoPbO42jdOXQbzMes9erLnZvl8/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: is this what you want to have? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsK5F.png

Comment: or this? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrDn1.png

Comment: @Chris second one, how did you do that? please tell my friend how did you eliminate all unexpected splines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the node tree:

[image]

unmute these two nodes to toggle

[image]

and of course here is the blend file, because you provided yours too...thanks for that! so i had less time effort!

[image]

it is pretty hard to explain but i try:

i just added these 3 selected nodes here:

[image]

by this additional "and" node ...

[image]

... i restrict the changing position (set position) not only to every 2nd line (modulo 2) but also only if they are hits.

by the delete geometry node ...

[image]

i delete all geometry which are not hits by the first raycasts.

Comment: if my answer helped you, please click on the checkmark left of my answer. Thank you!

Comment: can you please give a little explanation?

Comment: got it! Thanks a lot, my friend.

Comment: glad i could help